# How to decode result of LZ78 compression of string with numbers?

Tags: c, compression

I wrote a code for LZ78 compression algorithm in C. It works perfectly for strings such as "aabcccbac". But what if I have string: "1233" I get result: 01020333.

The problem is I don't know how to decode this kind of result. What should i do?

UPD:
Code that reads file and compress it:

```
FILE *file = fopen("test.txt", "rb");
FILE *pathFile = fopen("result.txt", "wb");
fread(text, 1, 100, file);

strcpy(result, lz78(text));
fwrite(result, 1, 100, pathFile);
```

Comment: Post exactly what you mean by `stroke: "1233"` and the code used to read it.

Comment: For example I have file test.txt that contains stroke "1233". I need to compress this stroke using LZ78 algorithm. After compressing i get result (0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(3,3). How to decode this string?

Comment: For reading I use fread()

Comment: Konstantin Tugeev By "stroke", do you mean _string_? or something else?  IAC, at some point you really need to post your code that reads the file, calls the compressor/decomressor  and reports the results.

Comment: Sorry for my english), i mean string

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: I doubt `lz78(text)` returns a _stirng_ and so calling `strcpy(result,...);` is the wrong approach.  As `lx78()` is not a standard function, post a documentation link for it.